# Show/hide jQuery script does not toggle elements correctly

Tags: jquery

I need jQuery script that:

1. by default will shown only one active div others will be hide
2. only one active at moment (if click newly hidden div -> it opens and currently opened div will close)

I have some code and a demonstration:

**HTML**

```
<div class="toggle">Content</div>
<div  class="hidden hide">Content</div>
<div class="toggle">Content</div>
<div  class="hidden show">Content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.toggle {width:398px; height:48px; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid #000}
.hidden {width:300px; height:75px; background-color:#333333; margin-left:50px; text-indent:25px;}

.hide {display:none;}
.show {display:block;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
       $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
       $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kolxoznik1/C7W2D/

Problem is that it doesn't close previously opened div correctly when open new.

Comment: You're aware of the [jQuery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion), right?

Comment: @Matt - If you would have put that in an answer, you'd have some votes by now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem.

It enables you to show and hide each div individually vs the snippet above that hides the previously open div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
       $().next('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
       $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/C7W2D/9/

Comment: The question being asked is to have only 1 _content_ `<div>` open at a time and your demo does not seem to hide the other `<div>`s

Answer (score 4):

Use this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
         $(".hidden").hide(); //to hide all
        $(this).next().show(); //to show the one you clicked on

    });
});
```

See it working here http://jsfiddle.net/C7W2D/4/

Comment: That's pretty close. I was working on that too. You're missing the click-to-close function. But that's it, nice and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this is to use the [jQuery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) plugin. You can use more semantically-sensible markup to achieve the same effect with less Javascript.

Restructured markup (h3's as clickable chunk, div's for content, paragraph elements to keen animation from being wonky):

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Header</a></h3>
    <div><p>Content</p></div>
    <h3><a href="#">Header</a></h3>
    <div><p>Content</p></div>
    <h3><a href="#">Header</a></h3>
    <div><p>Content</p></div>
    <h3><a href="#">Header</a></h3>
    <div><p>Content</p></div>
</div>
```

Javascript, after including jQuery UI:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/C7W2D/7/

There are also a bunch of options available, including the click-to-collapse ability you mentioned:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({collapsible: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
       var x= $(this).next();
       if(x.is(":visible")){
            x.hide();
       }else{
           $(".hidden").hide(); //to hide all
           x.show(); //to show the one you clicked on
       }
    });
});
```

In [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alfonsoR/uQYUZ/)...